# Some questions about integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I got those questions:

Prove or disprove the statement by a counterexample:
(1) If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$, Then there exist $c\in(a,b)$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx = f(c)(b-a)$.

(2) If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ that satisfies $\int_a^b f^2(x)\;dx = 0$, Then $\forall x\in[a,b], f(x)=0$.

(3) If $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that satisfy $\int_a^b f(t)\;dt=\int_a^b g(t)\;dt$, Then there exist $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$.

My try:
(1) I think this statement to be false since the MVT for Integrals says that there exist $c$ in the **closed interval** $[a,b]$ (and not in the **open interval** $(a,b)$ ) that satisfy $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx = f(c)(b-a)$ but I am having hard time finding a counterexample.
(2) I think this statement to be true but I tried to prove it but got stuck.
(3) This statement sounds true from an intuitive point of view and I tried to prove but didn't managed to proceed.

Some hints will be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: For (2) If $g(x)>0$ and $g(x)$ is integrable then $\int\limits_{a}^{b}{g(x)dx}>0$. For (3), see that $\int\limits_{a}^{b}{f(x)-g(x) \, dx}=0$ and use mean value theorem for integration.

Comment: For (1), you can actually find $c\in(a,b)$. See [this](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integ/integ04/integ04.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $(3)$, $$\int_a^bf(t)-g(t)=0$$. Then By IVT of integrals , there exists $$c \in (a,b)$$ such that $$\int_a^b\left(f(t)-g(t)\right)=\left(f(c)-g(c)\right)(b-a)=0$$. Since $$b-a \ne 0$$, we have $$f(c)=g(c)$$.

For $(2)$
$$f^2$$ is continuous, positive. If it's non zero at a point $c\in[a,b]$, there's an interval $]c−ϵ,c+ϵ[⊂[a,b]$ such that $f^2$ is strictly positive over $]c−ϵ,c+ϵ[$ . This contradicts $∫_a^bf^2(x)dx=0$.

Hence $f^2=0=f$.

For $(1)$, Set

$$F(x) = \displaystyle \int_{a}^{x}f (t)dt$$  .
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus implies $$F '(x) = f (x)$$. The Mean Value Theorem implies the existence of $c  \in (a, b)$ such that
$$\displaystyle {\frac{F(b) - F(a)}{b-a}} = F '(c)$$,    or equivalently    $$F(b) - F(a) = F '(c)\displaystyle \Big(b - a\displaystyle \Big)$$
which implies
$$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f (t)dt = f (c)\displaystyle \Big(b - a\displaystyle \Big)$$  .